# SCP client with 3 regions: 2x remote 1x local

Tags: windows, file-management, ssh

I am using WinSCP but I currently want to transfer files from one server to another, so I'd need at least 2 remote explorers. AFAIK, WinSCP only has a local and a remote explorer.

Yeah, you might ask why not establish a connection between the two servers directly? Because

- I'm simply not used to it.
- I'm using certificates and I don't want to store additional keys on the server
- multi-selection with mouse can be very convenient over typing
- drag'n'drop can be quite convenient

So, my requirements are:

- SCP client
- for Windows
- cost <50 EUR
- supports 2 connection at the same time
- has 2 remote explorer views + 1 local explorer view
- supports certificates (keys) for login
- can save favorite connections

Comment: Did you try FilleZilla? It should have all you need. But I hope not even WinSCP is using scp, but SFTP

Comment: @Jakuje: now as you say it, there's a *SFTP-3* text in the status bar... Must have suddenly appeared after you typed your comment :-)

Comment: Speaking of drag'n'drop: Have you tried opening a second instance of WinSCP (to "the other" server), and drag'n'drop your files between the 2 windows?